# jquery - How can send data when copy/pasted data in input?

Tags: php, jquery

I was send data when push the enter or click anywhere etc. People using my input field is with only copy/paste. Nobody write anything to input, only copy/paste. So I want, when copy/paste data to input field, send the data to target file. How can I do this?

Comment: use keyup event and compare length of your input. If the length more then 1, then a range was inserted (pasted).

Answer (score 1):

You can handle `copy/paste` activity by using the `input` event,

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('input',function(){
 //Code goes here..
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YnhwW/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the code send the data even if input is empty. I was control input with this code:

if($('#data').on('input') && $('#field').hasClass('active'))

I add the && $('#url').val() != '' but now worked.